# Non-continous Sobolev function in $W^{1,2}(B_1)$ for $B_1$ the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am currently studying for my Functional Analysis 2 exam and for a better understanding of Sobolev spaces I wanted to write down a function $u \in W^{1,2}(B_1)$ (for $B_1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$) which is not continous. Unfortunately I could not come up with any such function.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coud try the function $f(x)=\log(-\log|x|)$.

Comment: Why is this not continous? It is a composition of continous functions, so it should be continous itself, am I wrong?

Comment: This function goes to $-\infty$ at $0$, so it cannot be continuous at $0$.